# What's wrong with my String concatenation in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ by creating a String class for an embedded project and I have a problem with my String class' concatenation.

Here is my main method and the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    String s1("hello "), s2("world");
    String s3 = s1 + s2;
    cout << "s1=" << s1 << endl;
    cout << "s2=" << s2 << endl;
    cout << "s3=" << s3 << endl;
    return 0;
}

s1=hello 
s2=world
s3=hello
```

Rather than print out "hello world", it prints just "hello "

Here is my string.hpp class:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class String {
public:
    String() : c_str(NULL), len(0)
    {

    }

    String(const String& str) : c_str(new char[str.len]), len(str.len)
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str.c_str, len);
        c_str[len] = '\0';
    }

    String(const char* str) : String(str, strlen(str))
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str, len);
        c_str[len] = '\0';
    }

    String(const char* str, const int n) : len(n), c_str(new char[n+1])
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str, len);
    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete[] c_str;
    }

    const char* get_c_str()
    {
        return c_str;
    }

    bool contains(const String &cmd, const size_t pos)
    {
        return strncmp(c_str+pos, cmd.c_str, cmd.len) == 0;
    }

    size_t length()
    {
        return len;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String obj)
    {
        os << obj.c_str;
        return os;
    }

    friend void swap(String& s1, String& s2)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(s1.c_str, s2.c_str);
        swap(s1.len, s2.len);
    }

    bool operator==(const String& str)
    {
        return strncmp(c_str, str.c_str, len) == 0;
    }

    char operator[](const size_t i)
    {
        return c_str[i];
    }

    String& operator=(const String& src)
    {
        String tmp(src);
        swap(*this, tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    String operator+(const String& rhs)
    {
        const size_t new_len = len + rhs.len;
        char* new_c_arr = new char[new_len+1];

        strcpy(new_c_arr, c_str);
        strcat(new_c_arr, rhs.c_str);
        printf("new_c_arr=%s\n", new_c_arr);
        return String(new_c_arr, len);
    }

    String operator+(const char* rhs)
    {
        const size_t new_len = len + strlen(rhs) + 1;
        char* new_c_arr = new char[new_len];
        strcpy(new_c_arr, c_str);
        strcat(new_c_arr, rhs);
        return String(new_c_arr, new_len);
    }

private:
    char* c_str;
    int len;
};
```

I read about "the big 3" on SO while looking for a similar question and not sure if it because of this.

Comment: `return String(new_c_arr, len);` - wrong length

Comment: What's the point of using C string functions? Either use `std::string` or code it yourself if it's for training purpose

Comment: Your code leaks memory! in `operator +` you are throwing away the old content and allocate new memory.

Comment: This code is broken in so many different ways...

Comment: Yes, it is fully broken. In addition to leakage default construction with nullptr and no check for that but usage of zero pointer.

Comment: You'll probably benefit from posting your code on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) once it's working.

Comment: Your constructors are also not OK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is broken in numerous ways.

```
#pragma once
```

Actual include guards are more portable than `#pragma once`.

```
    String() : c_str(NULL), len(0)
    {

    }
```

Your default constructor makes `c_str` null; your other functions never check for this case. Remember that even an empty C string has one character.

```
    String(const String& str) : c_str(new char[str.len]), len(str.len)
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str.c_str, len);
        c_str[len] = '\0';
    }
```

You only allocated `str.len` characters for `c_str`, yet you are accessing `c_str[len]`.

```
    String(const char* str) : String(str, strlen(str))
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str, len);
        c_str[len] = '\0';
    }
```

The constructor to which you delegated already performed a copy. Why are you calling `strncpy` here again?

```
    String(const char* str, const int n) : len(n), c_str(new char[n+1])
    {
        strncpy(c_str, str, len);
    }
```

and here you didn't make sure that your string is null-terminated.

```
    const char* get_c_str()
    {
        return c_str;
    }
```

Should be marked `const`.

```
    bool contains(const String &cmd, const size_t pos)
    {
        return strncmp(c_str+pos, cmd.c_str, cmd.len) == 0;
    }
```

Ditto. And you didn't check that `pos` is in range.

```
    size_t length()
    {
        return len;
    }
```

`const`.

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String obj)
    {
        os << obj.c_str;
        return os;
    }
```

`obj` should be passed by const reference, not by value.

```
    bool operator==(const String& str)
    {
        return strncmp(c_str, str.c_str, len) == 0;
    }
```

`const` again, and the logic isn't even correct. By this logic, `"something" == "something else"` since you are only comparing the first `len` characters.

```
    char operator[](const size_t i)
    {
        return c_str[i];
    }
```

If you are returning a copy, then it should be `const`. If you want to allow users to modify the characters stored in the string, then it should return a `char &`. (Even better, have two separate overloads, one `const` and one non-`const`.)

```
    String operator+(const String& rhs)
    {
        const size_t new_len = len + rhs.len;
        char* new_c_arr = new char[new_len+1];

        strcpy(new_c_arr, c_str);
        strcat(new_c_arr, rhs.c_str);
        printf("new_c_arr=%s\n", new_c_arr);
        return String(new_c_arr, len);
    }
```

You are constructing the new string with the wrong length, and also leaking `new_c_arr`. And this function should be `const` (and really should be implemented in terms of `operator+=`, which you don't have).

```
    String operator+(const char* rhs)
    {
        const size_t new_len = len + strlen(rhs) + 1;
        char* new_c_arr = new char[new_len];
        strcpy(new_c_arr, c_str);
        strcat(new_c_arr, rhs);
        return String(new_c_arr, new_len);
    }
```

Leaking `new_c_arr` again; also, `new_len` here includes the null terminator, while the version in the other `operator+` doesn't. Your constructor taking a length does not appear to include the null terminator as part of the length.

Comment: Now THIS is thorough. I wonder if OP knows what `const` does to functions.

Comment: Not really, I thought it was just to stop being overided from inheriting sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line of problem in the method `String operator+(const String& rhs)`:

```
return String(new_c_arr, len);
```

You need to changed to this:

```
return String(new_c_arr, new_len+1);
```

You are initializing the returning String with a length equal to the first part only. Not the whole concatenated string.

See that the other operator is OK.

By the way you're creating a lot of new `char[]` in the `operator+` and the `constructor`.

In the case of the `operator+` you are creating a new `char[]` in every call and passing to the constructor of string (not deleting after), and in the constructor are creating a new `char[]` to storage the string that is deleted in the `destructor`, the new `char[]` created in the `operators` are leaked.

Comment: Take a look at the other answer before answering. Then you may find why you are wrong.

Comment: I don't see the other answer before I post mine, in that case I would not posted, because is almost the same. Really slow internet connection here

Comment: Yeah this happens. At least you saw your one mistake from mine. However, now you have a memory leak (and the OP's code has more problems too).